# Logging library and wfuzz not working together

Tags: python, logging, fuzzing

I've been using the python library logging with the wfuzz one. But since then, I don't know why but I cannot print out any logging level under warning. Here's my simple test :

```py
#without_wfuzz.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
#import wfuzz

logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('debug')
logging.info('info')
logging.warning('warning')
logging.error('error')
logging.critical('critical')
```

The output is as expected :
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Rlo.png)

And with the wfuzz library :

```py
#with_wfuzz.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
import wfuzz

logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('debug')
logging.info('info')
logging.warning('warning')
logging.error('error')
logging.critical('critical')
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vJNx.png)

Doing it while sudo doesn't help too. But I got the openssl error

> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/wfuzz/**init**.py:35: UserWarning:Pycurl is not compiled against Openssl. Wfuzz might not work correctly when fuzzing SSL sites. Check Wfuzz's documentation for more information.

Even if pycurl is well compiled with Openssl. I don't know if it has a link or not.

I've search everywhere and I don't think I understand how this is happening. I don't think the problems come from the logging library - it's like when importing wfuzz it reconfigure logging to warning and I cannot do anything... Any idea?
Thank you for any help!

*pycurl version (dep for wfuzz) : PycURL/7.43.0.6 libcurl/7.64.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1d zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.5 libpsl/0.20.2 (+libidn2/2.0.5) libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.36.0 librtmp/2.3*

*wfuzz version : 3.1.0*

*and I'm running on a clean debian buster*

Edit : it seems that defining the root logger before all the import solved my problem. Wfuzz must use logging and had a logging defined to warning that were overwriting my own config. Its working well now.

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
import wfuzz
```

Comment: You don't have to put the call before the import. You just can't use basicConfig and would have to setup your logging with the longer `getLogger` way. The issue is that `basicConfig` can detect when any logging is already configured and will abort if yes.

Answer (score 0):

You get problems when libraries configure logging rather than just instantiate loggers and log to them - it's the job of the top-level application to configure logging by calling `basicConfig()` or other configuration code. This should only be done once, in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` clause. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library) for how logging should be configured in libraries. I don't know if `wfuzz` (or some other dependency) is doing this, but problems can occur when logging is configured (by which I mean levels set, handlers/filters added) when a library module is imported.